# Wince 5.0 using STLport void *operator new(size_t,void *)' already has a body

Tags: visual-c++, windows-ce, stlport

I am doing a transform work from windows to wince.
For using iostream I choose `STLport5.2.1`.
I get the compile error on *vs2008*:

> am files (x86)\windows ce tools\wce500\athenapbws\mfc\include\wcealt.h(248) : error C2084: function 'void *operator new(size_t,void *)' already has a body
>
> 2>        D:\Program Files (x86)\Windows CE Tools\wce500\AthenaPBWS\include\ARMV4I../Armv4i/new(71) : see previous definition of 'new'
>
> 2>d:\program files (x86)\windows ce tools\wce500\athenapbws\mfc\include\wcealt.h(254) : error C2084: function 'void operator delete(void *,void *)' already has a body
>
> 2>        D:\Program Files (x86)\Windows CE Tools\wce500\AthenaPBWS\include\ARMV4I../Armv4i/new(73) : see previous definition of 'delete'
>
> 2>Util1.cpp
>   2>D:\Program Files (x86)\Windows CE Tools\wce500\AthenaPBWS\include\ARMV4I../Armv4i/new(72) : error C2084: function 'void *operator new(size_t,void *)' already has a body
>
> 2>        d:\program files (x86)\windows ce tools\wce500\athenapbws\mfc\include\wcealt.h(247) : see previous definition of 'new'
>
> 2>D:\Program Files (x86)\Windows CE Tools\wce500\AthenaPBWS\include\ARMV4I../Armv4i/new(74) : error C2084: function 'void operator delete(void *,void *)' already has a body
>
> 2>        d:\program files (x86)\windows ce tools\wce500\athenapbws\mfc\include\wcealt.h(253) : see previous definition of 'delete'

How can you solve the error?

Comment: When compiling for Windows CE 5.0 you need VS2005 or VS2008. Both come with a STL version for Windows CE. Why don't you use this STL implementation when you just need iostream?

Answer (score 1):

looks like you should define __PLACEMENT_NEW_INLINE - if was not already defined, here is what it does:

```
/* Workaround when using MFCCE and using  together: MFCCE's wcealt.h doesn't
 * check for __PLACEMENT_NEW_INLINE before defining operator new, so when 
 * defines the operatore before, there will be an error C2084:
 * "function 'void *__cdecl operator new(unsigned int,void *)' already has a body".
 */
#  ifdef _STLP_USE_MFC
#    define __PLACEMENT_NEW_INLINE
#  endif
```

Comment: I tried to define or undef  __PLACEMENT_NEW_INLINE in both <new> or <wcealt.h> but it seems invalid.

Comment: In fact when i added                                                   #  ifdef _STLP_USE_MFC                                              #    define __PLACEMENT_NEW_INLINE
#  endif                                                                                to wcealt.h the compile error decreased to 2,and the according code in <new> become grey. Why the compiler still tell me  error C2084: function 'void *operator new(size_t,void *)' already has a body

Comment: you should not modify wcealt.h, put any stlport configuration macros before including any of the stl headers, or better inside stlport\stl\config\user_config.h

Comment: I am sorry It doesn't help. Can you give me more details?

Answer (score 1):

you have to add the string --rtl-static in the configuration bat. 
This worked on me on wince. The output name of dll will be stlport-x.5.2.dll

**EDIT**

I've found the issue. I was able to build stlport with /MD (DLL Multithread) look at 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesnative/thread/fbae6f2a-4fc0-4610-a4b7-3d3d6bc6ac7e/